# index confusion: nested JavaScript loops - forEach within a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, indexing, foreach, nested

I want to use a forEach function inside a for loop for each element of an array to assign the index of the for loop to the elements.

my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
console.log('i:', i);
["element0", "element1", "element2"].forEach(function logArrayElements(element, i) {
    console.log('element:', element, 'index:', i);
});
}
```

the result:

```
i: 0
element: element0 index: 0
element: element1 index: 1
element: element2 index: 2
i: 1
element: element0 index: 0
element: element1 index: 1
element: element2 index: 2
```

what I am looking for:

```
i: 0
element: element0 index: 0
element: element1 index: 0
element: element2 index: 0
i: 1
element: element0 index: 1
element: element1 index: 1
element: element2 index: 1
```

Comment: Why are you using the variable name `i` twice?

Comment: `element3` ? you mean `element2`

Comment: @Ramanlfc yes, right. updated the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you said `element3` i'm assuming you meant `element2`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
console.log('i:', i);
["element0", "element1", "element2"].forEach(function (element, index) {
    console.log('element:', element, 'index:', i);
});
}
```

you used `i` as loop counter and as index in `forEach`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you supplied `i` as the name of the second argument of `forEach`, "shadowing" the `i` from the outside. Variable resolution starts from inner to outer, with inner taking precedence. That means, the callback will use the inner `i` instead of the outer `i`.

What you could do is rename either one of those variables so that the inner one won't shadow the outer one. Also, `i` is just a bad name. Name it to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different variables. You are using 'i' twice.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
console.log('i:', i);
["element0", "element1", "element3"].forEach(function logArrayElements(element, x) {
    console.log('element:', element, 'index:', x);
});
}
```